# How to disable a warning in Visual Studio 2015 for C?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am new in programming in C and I'm not used to work in Visual Studio 2015, my professor sent me a source code for a homework, but I'm obtaining the following error:

> Error C4996   'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider
>   using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

I already looked in the forums of Visual Studio. Nonetheless, I didn't understand how to disable this warning in order to be able to compile the application.

Comment: Right click on Project-> select Properties. In the Property pages go to C/C++-> Preprocessor -> add _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS to the preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In later versions of Visual Studio, [additional security checks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) are enabled by default on new projects, which makes the warning you see be treated as an error.

So, in addition to the actions in the suggested duplicate questions, you *may* also need to do the following.

Right click on the project in the solution explorer and choose Properties from the menu, then make sure you turn off SDL checks as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: sdl]

UPDATE (This alone worked for me):
[image]